# No funciona el método $(window).resize

Tags: jquery, eventos

Tengo un problema, pues mi `.resize()` no responde. Necesito que el script se ejecute para que al rotar un dispositivo móvil se ajuste el tamaño.

Este es mi script:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
        winHeightMobil = ($(window).height()) / 2;
        wWidth =  $(window).width();
        myElement = $('.Servicios');

    servFunction();
    function servFunction() {
        if (wWidth > 960) {
            myElement.height(winHeight)
        } else{
            myElement.height(winHeightMobil)
        }
    }
    $(window)
        .scroll(servFunction)
        .resize(servFunction)
});
```

Comment: En tu código no hay ningún evento llamado resize, solamente ejecutas una función al cargar la ventana

Comment: Gracias, suponía que con el $(window).scroll y $(window).resize cargaría, pero lo solucioné con un $(window).bind('resize', function()